# Which Header file need to use randomColor command in OpenCv?

Tags: c++, opencv

Which Header file need to use randomColor command in OpenCv? 
I use,
Opencv3.0.0
Visualstudio2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not within the headers. According to docs, the implementation is:

```
static Scalar randomColor( RNG& rng )
{
    int icolor = (unsigned) rng;
    return Scalar( icolor&255, (icolor>>8)&255, (icolor>>16)&255 );
}
```